# Прибавить к дате несколько дней

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прибавить к дате несколько дней в java. Вот код, если необходим:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
CalendarView cal;
private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    textView.setText("Дата готовых маток:");
    final  TextView nach = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.v1);
    final  TextView x1 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.v2);
    final  TextView x2 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.v3);
    final CalendarView c = root.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    c.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String a = String.format("%04d.%02d.%02d", year, month + 1, day);
            nach.setText(a);

            }





    });
    return root;
}

}
```

Спасибо большое заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Можно вместо SimpleDateFormat использовать Calendar:

```
String dt = "2012-01-04";  // начальная дата
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 40);  // can also use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH in place of Calendar.DATE
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String output = sdf1.format(c.getTime());
```

Вот [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738369/how-to-add-days-into-the-date-in-android/12995000) и [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar)

Comment: Android studio выдает ошибку:                                                `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date     com.example.beecalc.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment$1.onSelectedDayChange(GalleryFragment.java:51)`

Comment: я не вижу на что указывает ошибка и что именно вы взяли из моего ответа, но вам нужно сформировать стринг как в моем ответе, день год и месяц вы сможете взять из виджета

Comment: Понял, извините. Указал информацию в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, как я изменил код, исходя из Вашего ответа:

```
public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String a = String.format("%02d.%02d.%04d", day, month + 1, month);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                c.setTime(s.parse(a));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);  // can also use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH in place of Calendar.DATE
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            nach.setText(sdf1.format(a));
```

Ошибка, которую выдает Android Studio: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`
Указывает она на строку: `nach.setText(sdf1.format(a))`

Comment: Приложите это к вопросу а не ответ публикуйте!!!

Comment: Я бы вам предложил воспользоваться только моим методом а не лепить все вместе